# Delete elements from list based on substring in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a huge list of strings where a couple of strings only differ in 2 or three characters like this:

```
ENSH-DFFEV1-5F
ENSH-DFFEV2-5F
ENSH-DFFEV3-5F
FVB.DFFVRV2-4T
FVB.DFFVRV3-4T
```

What I would like to do is to keep only those elements for which the number after the 'V' is the largest. From the above example I would like to have

```
ENSH-DFFEV3-5F
FVB.DFFVRV3-4T
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We help with *specific* code problems. Please read through the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Are these elements in the certain list? Or they are located in file?

Comment: are they always grouped together like in your example?

Comment: also, if they are grouped, are they always increasing the number after V like in your example?

Comment: @jacoblaw Yes, they are always grouped together like this, increasing number after the V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stevieb is right, but anyway, I did the effort for you.

```
s = """
ENSH-DFFEV1-5F
ENSH-DFFEV2-5F
ENSH-DFFEV3-5F
FVB.DFFVRV2-4T
FVB.DFFVRV3-4T
""".split()

def custom_filter(s):
    out = []
    current_max = -1
    for r in s:
        v = int(r.rsplit('-', 1)[0][-1]) # <- you should probably edit this line to fit your data structure 
        if v > current_max:
            current_max = v
            out = []
        if v == current_max:
            out += [r]
    return out

for e in custom_filter(s):
    print e
```